# JUnit how to save DisplayName in xml report file

Tags: java, junit, appium

I want to generate XML report file with info of executed tests. Previously I used shown below `@Rule` in JUnit4 but now I want to display comment or some short of short description instead of testName. After some research I found `@DisplayName`in JUnit5 that seems to suit my needs. Now I have to update my `@Rule` to display `@DisplayName`content instead of `testName[number].className`.
Tests are written in JUnit classes and have following structure

```
@Test
@DisplayName("This text should be displayed as name")
public void testy1() {...}
```

To display outcome and name of run test I created new rule with following scheme

```
@Rule
public TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
                return super.apply(base, description);
            }
@Override
protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        try {

            junitWriter.write("\n   <test>"
                            + "\n       <name>" + description.getDisplayName() + "</name>"
                            + "\n       <result>..
                            + "\n       <message>..
                            + "\n   </test>");
        } catch [..]
    }
@Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            //same scheme with error
        }
}
```

To start tests I run

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(mainSuiteClassCreatingReport);
System.out.printf("Test ran: %s, Failed: %s%n", result.getRunCount(), result.getFailureCount());
```

In generated XML file instead of "DisplayName" annotation I keep getting `methodName[number].className`. Can anybody help me to display/save it the way I want?

Comment: You are mixing JUnit 4 and 5 API ... and you don't tell us which tool you use to execute your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Hopefully I understood you correctly so I just sligthly changed the question
Edit: I do not care if I use JUnit4 or 5 as long as I can display my personal string in place of `testName[0].className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `@DisplayName` with JUnit 4.

If you want to use `@DisplayName`, you'll need to switch to JUnit Jupiter (a.k.a., JUnit 5) and implement an `Extension`.

Note that JUnit Jupiter does not yet support an extension API like the `TestWatcher` rule from JUnit 4; however, such support is coming in JUnit 5.4: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/542

To customize what is returned from `getDisplayName()` in `Description` in JUnit 4, you would need to write your own custom `Runner`. As an alternative, you could simply parse the value returned from `getDisplayName()` and use that to generate your own display name.

Or, if you want to support your own custom display name annotation with JUnit 4, such as this:

```
package foo;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyDisplayName {

    String value();

}
```

You could look it up in your `TestWatcher` implementation using reflection like this:

```
package foo;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class ExampleTests {

    @Rule
    public TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher() {

        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            System.out.println("Display name: " + getDisplayName(description));
        }

        private String getDisplayName(Description description) {
            Class<?> testClass = description.getTestClass();
            String methodName = description.getMethodName();
            try {
                Method method = testClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
                MyDisplayName myDisplayName = method.getAnnotation(MyDisplayName.class);
                return myDisplayName.value();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // do something with the exception if you want...
            }
            // default:
            return testClass.getName() + "." + methodName + "()";
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void testWithoutCustomDisplayName() {
    }

    @Test
    @MyDisplayName("Custom display name!")
    public void testWithCustomDisplayName() {
    }

}
```

Running that test class outputs the following:

```
Display name: foo.ExampleTests.testWithoutCustomDisplayName()
Display name: Custom display name!
```

Comment: So in conclusion to customize `Description` in JUnit4 I need to create my own Runner? Is there a way that I can i.e. add new parameter to `Description` so I could use it like: `Description description; 
description.myCustomString; or description.myCustomFunction();`

Comment: Well, all constructors for `Description` are `private`. So you cannot subclass it to add any additional fields.

Comment: What you could do is create your own annotation for a custom display name and then look up that annotation on the current test method. From the `Description`, you can invoke `getTestClass()` and `getMethodName()` and then use a bit of reflection magic to find the `java.lang.Method` from which you can retrieve your custom annotation.

Comment: Can you show some scheme example? Or explain what you mean by "use a bit of reflection magic"? I'm new to junit and whole test automation itself

Comment: I just updated my answer with a fully working example for JUnit 4 based on reflection. Feel free to accept the answer if it in fact answers your question. ;-)